# Listview not displaying anything, but debugger show data

Tags: android, listview

```
 void beginListenForData() {
        //final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];//It uses a 1024 bytes long buffer because it doesn't have any way of knowing the length of the input stream.
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                    try {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b == delimiter) {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;
                                    //runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                        public void run() {
                                            final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

                                                list.add(data);
                                                //Log.d("data",data);

                                            adapter = new ArrayAdapter
                                                    (Bluetooth_dataDisplay.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                                            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                                            Log.d("data", data);
                                            //myLabel.setText(data);
                                            //dataArray = new String []{data};
                                            //Log.d("dataArray", data);
                                        }
                                    });

                                } else {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();
    }
```

Hi I trying to display my data in a listview so I can display more data. But I not getting anything display. I tried debugging the code and below is the result 
[result of debugging][1]  :( Please help I been trying different ways to display data and i am really stuck here.

Comment: because you are adding you `ArrayList` to your adapter

Comment: @Mohit hi what you mean?? can provide more details :( Thank you!

Comment: i already gave you an example how to pass some data from the background thread to the ui thread, didn't i?

Comment: try this `adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Bluetooth_dataDisplay.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);`

Comment: @pskink hi it didn't work. :( I getting null value. So I stopped using recycleviewer

Comment: what RecyclerView? it has nothing to do with that

Comment: Where you are setting data, in the adapter?

Comment: @pskink Hi I mean the purpose of me wanting to get data from background thread to UI is because I was using recycle veiwer on other activity. But I really stuck. So I changed my code instead. sorry about that and thanks for your help

Comment: @Mohit Hi it worked. But I not getting the data in a list. I posted the two photos of the data. I am getting the data in the same row and flashing. How do I separate them?

Comment: @Mohit hi if you don't mind explaining why adding a list behind mean? Thanks!

Comment: @NigamPatro hi what you mean where I set my data?

Comment: list is the data you are setting to adapter before assinging to listview

Comment: @Mohit ok thanks! Do you have any idea how to separate the data? because right now my data are just flashing between temperature and RBPM %Spo2

Comment: is your previous problem solved?

Comment: @Mohit hi yes solved! So my only problem is data appeared in same row. I took a video of it (link here) https://www.dropbox.com/s/hb2gnfr653tbmca/Video%2021-12-15%2C%2010%2053%2006%20PM.mov?dl=0

Comment: you have to use list.setAdapter after the thread finish

Comment: @helldawg13 hi! You are answering the flashing data question?

Comment: yes this is what i am answering

Comment: @helldawg13 Hi I placed the code here(following the answer below)   workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Bluetooth_dataDisplay.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    }); But honestly I don't know what is going on. If you don't mind explaining it? It worked though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not put the data in the adapter.

> ```
> while (...)
>     {
>     ...
>     for (...)
>         {
>         ...
>         handler.post(new Runnable() {
>             public void run() {
>                 final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
>                 list.add(data);
>                 adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Bluetooth_dataDisplay.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
>                 listview.setAdapter(adapter);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Change the structure of your code to look like this intsead:

```
// Where you initialize the view, eg onCreate() of an Activity
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Bluetooth_dataDisplay.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);

// Where you are loading the data (shown in the question)
while (...)
     {
     ...
     for (...)
         {
         ...
         handler.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 adapter.add(data);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

You want to create one, and only one, `Adapter` and configure the `ListView` to display its contents.  There is no need to create a new `ArrayList` to contain a single element each time you have the data.  You do need to add the data to the adapter.

### -----

A `ListView` object displays the data it gets from the `Adapter` to which it refers. This abstraction is designed so that you can completely control how the data is obtained, how it is structured, and how to manage it.  The ListView doesn't care, it only cares that it has something it can use (the Adapter) to do what it needs.  So you create an adapter and connect it to the ListView.

Since an array (or rather, an ArrayList) is a common and straightforward way to represent simple linear collections of data, the Android platform provides a built-in implementation called `ArrayAdapter` so that you don't need to reimplement that functionality.  Since this is appropriate for your use, use it.

Often it is in the Activity's `onCreate()` method that you would initialize the views.  So there as you initialize them, you create the adapter and pass a reference to the ListView so that it can get the data from it and notice when the data in it changes.  This is something you only want to do once, so don't put it inside a loop.

In your worker thread you retrieve all the data.  As you receive the data you need to add it to the adapter.  If it isn't added to the adapter, then the ListView has no way to know that it exists or that it should do anything with it.  In your original code, other than logging the data you never did anything else with it.  You created an ArrayList, put the object in it, logged it, and that was it.  Each time through the loop you created a new ArrayList, so each time the list contained exactly one object.  Since nothing the only references to that data, and that new ArrayList, were local variables inside the loop, that data would soon be garbage collected because that memory was no longer reachable and thus is will not be used.  You also created a new adapter object, never added anything to it so it remained forever empty, and instructed the ListView to display the data in that new and empty adapter.

The difference is that my code adds each data to the adapter.  Thus the adapter does not remain empty, and so the ListView will display the data contained in the adapter.

Comment: Hi i tried your way but  I got this error and my app crashed Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: You need to set up the view (namely calling `listView.setAdapter()` on the UI thread, not in your worker thread. Do that where you set up the rest of the view(s).

Comment: where do I put these? adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Bluetooth_dataDisplay.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
handler.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

Comment: HI! it worked! Thanks! Now I getting my data separately! :) But if you don't mind could you explain more on the code??? Would like to learn.

Comment: I added a long-winded description of the behaviour of the code to my answer.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the explanation! You mentioned that  This abstraction is designed so that you can completely control how the data is obtained, how it is structured, and how to manage it. So it is possible to use listview to display a updated value for two different data in a separate row. I posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407661/how-do-i-display-data-with-values-updated-in-a-textview

Comment: Yes, you can update the data shown in the ListView. It applies the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). The ListView [registers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#registerDataSetObserver(android.database.DataSetObserver)) with the Adapter so that the Adapter can [notify](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) it when the data has changed.

Comment: Hi I posted a question here link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407661/how-do-i-display-data-with-values-updated-in-a-textview/34407701#34407701 Can this be done using listview?